# Generic class with type as pointer to object of another class - NOT WORKING

Tags: c++, templates, generics, pointers, vector

Why isn't this working:

```
class/struct SomeClass
{
public:
      int     SomeValue;
}

template <class/struct/typename T> class/struct TClass
{
public:
        T     TObject;
}

vector<TClass<SomeClass*>> *vTcSomeClass = new vector<TClass<SomeClass*>>();
```

Is this illegal or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? can you give us the error message?

Comment: also, can you edit the post to contain the _exact_ code you used?

Comment: you want divide class by struct? It willn't work!

Comment: I hope you are not actually writing `class/struct` in your code. If so, just use `class` everywhere.

Comment: If you do not use c++0x, then `>>` will be interpreted as right shift instead of closing angle brackets. Write `> >` instead.

Comment: "Is this illegal or am I just doing it wrong?" -- Yes.

Comment: "Generics" or "generic class" *is not C++*. Please start with a good introductory book on C++.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'm programming Java or something then.
Error message is: error C2664: 'TClass<T>::TClass(const TClass<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TClass<T> *' to 'const TClass<T> &'

Comment: And as people think the worse all the time, I guess you guessed that I put struct/class/template at the same time. I always minimalize my code to the minimum amount to explain it instead of sending the whole code. So, I'm sorry for not giving you all alot more to read on.

Comment: @Deukalion we didn't need more to read, we needed some small code sample that clearly illustrates the problem. With your `struct/class/template` there are too many possibilities where it could have gone wrong.

Comment: `new vector<whatever>` is also a warning sign. You shouldn't really need to `new` a standard container under any normal circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code should compile if you:

- choose one of class/struct in types and one of class/typename in template parameters
- use semicolons after class or struct definitions
- write `> >` instead of `>>` in nested templates (pre C++11)

Comment: On your first point, I don't think you _can_ use `struct` in the template<> can you?! I thought you could only use `class` or `typename`. On your third point, you only need that if you don't have a modern compiler.

Comment: `struct` won't work as template parameter.

Comment: I had it earlier, just wrote an example of what my code looks like to minimalize the code. I've tried with structs/class/template, which is why I added those which I hoped people understood. I also have it nested < < > > instead of <<>>, still won't work.

Comment: error C2664: 'TClass<T>::TClass(const TClass<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TClass<T> *' to 'const TClass<T> &'

Comment: Well, the error was unrelated to the question. Just thought it had something to with this.